# Is this a valid use of indicator constraints in an LP-format CPLEX integer program?

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, integer-programming

I'm trying to understand the use of indicator constraints in CPLEX. I have specified a simple integer programming problem to solve in the CPLEX Interactive Optimizer. For various reasons I am unable to use any of the CPLEX APIs for this task.

The real problem is a simple maximum covering set problem but with a large number of variables.There a number of types of THING, which are found in one or more BOXES. I want to maximise the number of types of THING in my solution, whilst keeping the number of BOXES below a constraint. All variables are binaries.

The real problem is obviously a lot bigger. I have produced a trivial version here, with a constraint of 3 BOXES.

```
MAXIMIZE
obj: THING1 + THING2 + THING3 + THING4 + THING5 + THING6 + THING7 + THING8 + THING9 + THING10
SUBJECT TO
nboxes: BOX1 + BOX2 + BOX3 + BOX4 + BOX5 + BOX6 <=3
box1_indicator: BOX1 = 1 -> THING1 + THING2 + THING3 = 3
box2_indicator: BOX2 = 1 -> THING4 + THING5 + THING6 = 3
box3_indicator: BOX3 = 1 -> THING7 + THING8 + THING9 = 3
box4_indicator: BOX4 = 1 -> THING10 + THING1 = 2
box5_indicator: BOX5 = 1 -> THING1 + THING5 + THING9 + THING10 = 4
box6_indicator: BOX6 = 1 -> THING3 + THING4 = 3
thing1_indicator: THING1 = 1 -> BOX1 + BOX4 + BOX5 >=1
thing2_indicator: THING2 = 1 -> BOX1 >=1
thing3_indicator: THING3 = 1 -> BOX1 + BOX6 >=1
thing4_indicator: THING4 = 1 -> BOX2 + BOX6 >=1
thing5_indicator: THING5 = 1 -> BOX2 + BOX5 >=1
thing6_indicator: THING6 = 1 -> BOX2 >=1
thing7_indicator: THING7 = 1 -> BOX3 >=1
thing8_indicator: THING8 = 1 -> BOX3 >=1
thing9_indicator: THING9 = 1 -> BOX3 + BOX5 >=1
thing10_indicator: THING10 = 1 -> BOX4 + BOX5 >=1

BINARIES
THING1
THING2
THING3
THING4
THING5
THING6
THING7
THING8
THING9
THING10
BOX1
BOX2
BOX3
BOX4
BOX5
BOX6

END
```

My first question is: is this formulation of the problem using only indicator constraints valid? In my real example it can be run with CPLEX happily and I have not found it to produce unexpected solutions. Answering this question is a prerequisite for the one below.

My second question is: I wanted to introduce a constraint that I only want solutions that sample THING1 twice. I replaced the indicator constraint

```
   thing1_indicator: THING1 = 1 -> BOX1 + BOX4 + BOX5 >=1
```

with

```
   thing1_indicator: THING1 = 1 -> BOX1 + BOX4 + BOX5 >=2
```

In my real problem, the RHS of this constraint seems to be ignored. CPLEX reads and optimises without complaint, and the solutions returned give a value for THING1 as 1, but would (for example) have BOX1 = 1, BOX4 = 0, BOX5 = 0.

This makes me concerned that either I have completely missed the point in the use of indicator contraints in LP format programs, or that there's something about the priority of handling indicator constraints that is causing this problem.

One other thing that occurred to me was that CPLEX's presolve routines might be removing a constraint somewhere, but I thought I would check the obvious before digging into the pre solve output.

Answer (score 1):

You can write these as linear constraints which can be handled by cplex.  The constraint box1_indicator can be written

```
box1_indicator: THING1 + THING2 + THING3 - 3 * BOX1 >= 0
```

If BOX1 is 1, then the constraint becomes `THING1 + THING2 + THING3 >= 3` and which can only be satisfied if the sum is exactly 3.  If BOX1 is zero, then the constraint becomes `THING1 + THING2 + THING3 >= 0` which is always true.

And similarly

```
thing1_indicator: BOX1 + BOX4 + BOX5 - THING1 >= 0
```

Comment: My original formulation looked like that - thanks! - but I started using indicator constraints because this syntax 'box1_indicator: THING1 + THING2 + THING3 >=3 * BOX1' produces the warning 'Characters after RHS value are ignored.' and checking the problem after CPLEX has read it in confirms that the constraint is 'THING1 + THING2 + THING3 >=3' only. Is this a version problem? I'm using the Interactive Optimizer 12.5.0.0